# How to alter timestamps on specific rows in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a `pandas` `df` that contains different timestamps and `strings` within the same `column`. An example is displayed below:

Once time goes past midnight the data spits out this weird 351 code and then reverts back to 12 hr time. So below the time for `row 5` is actually 12:01:42 and `row 8` will be 13:00:00.

I can add 12 hours to these timestamps but I need to get rid of the first 3 values.

I have tried to do this by indexing the appropriate times (after midnight) and applying `[x[3:] for x in df]`. But this removes the strings within this column. So `AA` and `BB` are removed as well.

I'm a bit stuck on how to achieve this without removing unspecified values. Is it possible to select the appropriate times (only timestamps) after midnight, remove 351, and add 12 hours without losing any data?

```
import pandas as pd

k = 5
N = 10

d = ({'Time' : ['18:00:00','AA','BB', '23:00:00','AA','35112:01:42','AA','AA','35113:00:00','AA'],
'Events' : ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','DEF','JKL'],
'Number1' : ['xx','xx',1,'xx','xx','xx',2,'xx', 'xx', 1]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output:

```
  Events Number1         Time
0    ABC      xx     18:00:00
1    DEF      xx           AA
2    GHI       1           BB
3    JKL      xx     23:00:00
4    ABC      xx           AA
5    DEF      xx  35112:01:42
6    GHI       2           AA
7    JKL      xx           AA
8    DEF      xx  35113:00:00
9    JKL       1           AA
```

Intended Output:

Output:

```
  Events Number1         Time
0    ABC      xx     18:00:00
1    DEF      xx           AA
2    GHI       1           BB
3    JKL      xx     23:00:00
4    ABC      xx           AA
5    DEF      xx     24:01:42
6    GHI       2           AA
7    JKL      xx           AA
8    DEF      xx     25:00:00
9    JKL       1           AA
```

Comment: @wwii I dunno, this looks to be a little more involved than the link you suggested... I would not be satisfied with that.

Comment: `351` code is weird though. I wonder what it means...

Comment: @coldspeed- IThe OP stated `I can add 12 hours to these timestamps` so I thought the problem was removing the  unwanted text.

Comment: @wwii this is true. The main difference compared to the other question is the additional strings within the column. As mentioned in the question, when I alter the timestamps in the column it also removes the other values. The other question doesn't contain anything but timestamps in the column.

Comment: Can the other strings, `AA, BB`, start with `351`?

Comment: No. The strings in my dataset differ, but they mainly contain 4 letters. They are interspersed with the timestamps and aren't in any reoccurring order. So I can't just apply the function to every n row. That's why it's different from the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `str.replace` with a callable:

```
df['Time'] = df.Time.str.replace(r'351(\d{2})', lambda x: str(12 + int(x.group(1))))
```

Alternatively, you can squeeze out a little more performance using `re.compile` and a list comprehension:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'351(\d{2})')
df['Time'] = [
    p.sub(lambda x: str(12 + int(x.group(1))), y) for y in df['Time'].tolist()
]
```

```
df
  Events Number1      Time
0    ABC      xx  18:00:00
1    DEF      xx        AA
2    GHI       1        BB
3    JKL      xx  23:00:00
4    ABC      xx        AA
5    DEF      xx  24:01:42
6    GHI       2        AA
7    JKL      xx        AA
8    DEF      xx  25:00:00
9    JKL       1        AA
```

Comment: You can take way group ?? Im seeing it for the first time. Good one

Comment: @Dark Yes, you can reference capture groups in the callable, just like `re.sub`.

Answer (score 2):

**`str.replace`** with **`lambda`** and **`group`** to add 12

```
def add_twelve(t):
    return str(int(t[:2]) + 12) + t[2:]

df.Time.str.replace(r'\d{3}(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', lambda x: add_twelve(x.group(1))) 

0    18:00:00
1          AA
2          BB
3    23:00:00
4          AA
5    24:01:42
6          AA
7          AA
8    25:00:00
9          AA
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

Comment: I was thinking `'^351'` for the pattern.

Comment: @wwii I assumed that the `AA` etc were just dummy strings so made it as specific as possible.

Comment: There are definitely advantages to making the pattern explicit/specific.

Comment: I did see some other posts but as @coldspeed mentioned my specific df had some peculiar nuances.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mask and then apply some string operations i.e

```
mask = df['Time'].str.startswith('351')

df.loc[mask,'Time'] = (df[mask]['Time'].str[3:].str[:2].astype(int)+12).astype(str) + df[mask]['Time'].str[3:].str[2:]


    Events Number1    Time
0    ABC      xx  18:00:00
1    DEF      xx        AA
2    GHI       1        BB
3    JKL      xx  23:00:00
4    ABC      xx        AA
5    DEF      xx  24:01:42
6    GHI       2        AA
7    JKL      xx        AA
8    DEF      xx  25:00:00
9    JKL       1        AA
```

Since its 351 that needs to be removed slicing it is the way chosen i.e

```
df[mask]['Time'].str[3:]

5    12:01:42
8    13:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: object

(df[mask]['Time'].str[3:].str[:2])

5    12
8    13
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt would be:

create a column for indexing the corrupted data:

```
df['corruptedTime'] = df.Time.str.startswith('351')
```

removing the 'weird 351':

```
df.loc[df.corruptedTime, 'Time'] = df.Time[df.corruptedTime].str.slice(3)
```

adding 12 to the hour and calc modulo 24:

```
df.loc[df.corruptedTime, 'Time'] = df.Time[df.corruptedTime].apply(lambda s: str((int(s[:2]) + 12) % 24).zfill(2) + s[2:])
```

drop the indexer if not needed anymore:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['corruptedTime'])

  Events Number1      Time
0    ABC      xx  18:00:00
1    DEF      xx        AA
2    GHI       1        BB
3    JKL      xx  23:00:00
4    ABC      xx        AA
5    DEF      xx  00:01:42
6    GHI       2        AA
7    JKL      xx        AA
8    DEF      xx  01:00:00
9    JKL       1        AA
```